# /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Root element is missing. [~/projects/test-proj/test-proj.csproj]

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

So now `dotnet restore` started throwing this error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Root element is missing. [/home/francardoso/projects/test-proj/test-proj.csproj]
```

It happens for existing projects, but also if I try to create a fresh new webapi.

Already tried to reinstall dotnet.

Why is this happening?

```
$ dotnet new webapi -n test-proj
The template "ASP.NET Core Web API" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on test-proj/test-proj.csproj...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Root element is missing. [/home/francardoso/projects/test-proj/test-proj.csproj]

Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Description: Restore NuGet packages required by this project.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'

dotnet restore /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Root element is missing. [/home/francardoso/projects/test-proj/test-proj.csproj]
```

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.402
 Commit:    c7f2f96116

 Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/

 Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.8
  Commit:  b9aa1abc51

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: my guess would be that you have a nuget.config file somewhere that isn't valid XML. But without a repro that I can run on my own machine, all I can do is wildly speculate (worse than a guess).

Comment: Can you increase verbosity and re-run and dotnet restore and share the output? `dotnet restore --verbosity:normal`

Answer (score 0):

Same on dotnet sdk 6.0.405. Clearing nuget cache worked for me:

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```